# Failed to load resource, error 404, running with IIS Local

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-7

Good morning, I developed a mvc 5 application, during development I used IIS Express, all the files there loaded perfectly, when I uploaded to my IIS Local (7) still on my machine to test, I realized that several files are not loaded.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
```

When checking I identified that the file is not loaded because in fact, the path that tries to perform the GET is incorrect. It tries to get get on the path:

```
http://localhost/content/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
```

But the correct file would be:

```
http://localhost/aprovacoes/content/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
```

In the get, the project name is missing, due to this it is not loaded.

To solve the problem of this particular source, I needed to edit the bootstrap.min.css file and change the url from url:

```
url(/content/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff)
```

for

```
url(aprovacoes/content/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff)
```

However in every project several files are not loaded, and to solve I'm editing the css file by file, would not there be another way to map this correct path in all css files?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: It seems odd to me that you would need the project name in the url, but that would depend on your setup of iis and how the project is setup and published.

If you could add information on the setups that might be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a resource-relative path. For example, if you have a file structure like:

```
+ bootstrap.css
- fonts
    + glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
```

Then, use the URL: `fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff`. Or if it's something like:

```
- css
    + bootstrap.css
- fonts
    + glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
```

Then, you'd use: `../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff`.

That way, it won't matter how or where the site is deployed, as long as the relative path between the files remains consistent.

Comment: In some files really worked perfectly, however in some urls that are inside the css already loaded, I had to manually change, anyway, I was able to make the adjustments more easily, thanks.